# Meaning of the parameters for EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

The parameter for `EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR` and `EM_LINEFROMCHAR` are different.

While I can find the example of the latter the former does not produce any useful links.

What I wonder is - if I pass `-1` just like in `EM_LINEFROMCHAR` to `EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR` for the current line where the caret is located will it work properly. MSDN unfortunately doesn't explain it.

TIA!!

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-exlinefromchar) (was linked to from `EM_LINEFROMCHAR`) - it is my impression that this is meant primarily for rich text edits, which can have more than 64K lines.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, yes, I am. And yes - it is for the RTC.

Comment: Use EM_GETSEL to get the current position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the documentation for [`EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-exlinefromchar) says only the following about the input parameters:

> *wParam*
> This parameter is not used; it must be zero
>
> *lParam*
> Zero-based index of the character.

There is no mention of whether `-1` is allowed or not, so there is no guaranteed whether it will work or not.  Best not to take any chances.  Simply don't pass in `-1`, pass in the actual caret position, which is very trivial to get using [`EM_GETSEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getsel) or [`EM_EXGETSEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-exgetsel), eg:

```
DWORD pos = 0;
SendMessage(hwnd, EM_GETSEL, (WPARAM)&pos, 0);
int lineIndex = SendMessage(hwnd, EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR, 0, pos);
```

```
CHARRANGE rng = {};
SendMessage(hwnd, EM_EXGETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&rng);
int lineIndex = SendMessage(hwnd, EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR, 0, rng.cpMin);
```

Whereas [`EM_LINEFROMCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-linefromchar) is explicitly documented, and thus contractually obligated, to accept `-1` as input:

> *wParam*
> The character index of the character contained in the line whose number is to be retrieved. **If this parameter is -1, `EM_LINEFROMCHAR` retrieves either the line number of the current line (the line containing the caret) or, if there is a selection, the line number of the line containing the beginning of the selection.**
>
> *lParam*
> This parameter is not used.

```
int lineIndex = SendMessage(hwnd, EM_LINEFROMCHAR, (WPARAM)-1, 0);
```

Comment: I am coming from this answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f78cff7f-b69a-4bea-ac11-c1a48909d4d8/richedit-how-can-i-get-the-caret-position?forum=vclanguage. Unfortunately it uses regular message and not the `EX` one. Can you post some code for me using any of the messages mentioned?

Comment: @Igor I have updated my answer

Comment: @RemyLabeau, thx, I'll try it later.

Comment: @RemyLabeau, I accepted your answer. Thank you.